# Somar coluna table com javascript e condição

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esta função que soma os campos de uma coluna da `table` e funciona perfeitamente:

```
let result = 0;
    let columns = $("#tablepesquisaprodutos tr td:nth-child(" + 8 + ")");

    columns.each(i => {
        result += parseFloat($(columns[i]).html().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    });
```

Porém surgiu a necessidade de somar somente os campos onde a coluna 19 for true, como posso fazer tudo isto na mesma função ? 
Detalhe: Neste caso é uma `table` dinâmica, que preencho por jquery.

Este é o HTML da `table`

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped" id="tablepesquisaprodutos" style="font-size:12px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Descrição</th>
                            <th>Qtd</th>
                            <th>Preço Un.</th>
                            <th>Desc %</th>
                            <th>Desc R$</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>ICMS</th>
                            <th>Alíquota</th>
                            <th>V.ICMS</th>
                            <th>%ISS</th>
                            <th>V.ISS</th>
                            <th>%IPI</th>
                            <th>V.IPI</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody><tr class="item"><td><input type="checkbox" class="link-check" onchange="cbChange(this);"></td>
                        <td>P00082</td>
                        <td>teste</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td>0,00</td>
                        <td style="display: none;">1</td>
                        <td style="display: none;">82</td>
                        <td style="display: none;">08/11/2018</td>
                        <td style="display: none;">true</td>
</tr></tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Você pode usar o filter do jQuery.
Coloque o HTML da sua tabela para ficar mais fácil de demonstrar.

Comment: @Andre eu preencho esta tabela dinamicamente por jquery, vou  editar a resposta.

Comment: Abra as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e copie o HTML já renderizado da sua página. A solução vai depender de como esse "false" é representado. O que essa variável "Tipo" contém? Ele é um booleano? Um checkbox?

Comment: É do tipo string, preciso verificar se está com true ou false. Como expliquei a table é preenchida dinamicamente.

Comment: Mas não importa se a tabela é preenchida dinamicamente, você pode pegar o HTML dela com as ferramentas de desenvolvedor. Adicione uma linha a ela, aperte F12, localize a tabela no seu HTML e copie-a.

Comment: @Andre pronto. Editei a pergunta. Eu preciso somar a coluna total, conforme a condição da ultima coluna, se for false e se for true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar `:contains()` para selecionar todas as linhas onde a coluna 19 contém o texto "*true*". E usando `.siblings()` irá selecionar a coluna irmã especificada (no caso, a coluna 8).

O [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) seleciona todos os elementos que contém um determinado texto. Desta forma não precisa criar uma função com `filter()`.

Sendo assim, não precisa mudar nada no seu código, apenas os seletores da variável `columns`:

```
let result = 0;
let columns = $("#tablepesquisaprodutos tr")
               .find("td:nth-child(19):contains('true')") 
               .siblings("td:nth-child(" + 8 + ")");

columns.each(i => {
   console.log($(columns[i]).html());
   result += parseFloat($(columns[i]).html().replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
});
```

Comment: Entendi, não conhecia o `:contains()`, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, é sempre bom conhecer mais coisas.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Filtra apenas os trs que possuem true como texto interno*/
let trs = $('#tablepesquisaprodutos tr').filter((i, e) => $(e).find('td:nth-child(19)').html() === 'true');

/*Encontra o oitavo elemento da coluna*/
let columns = trs.find('td:nth-child(8)');
```